# How to use Write a sql query in servlet

Tags: java

Hello guys i am trying to do a school  project.I have written a login page.It is not complete becausw i want the id_user after logging in, and can’t find a way how to catch it in the servlet package(how to write a sql query inside the servlet).
After catching the id i wil use session
Thank you for your time

Dao package:

```
package en.xx.project.dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import en.xxx.project.conn.DBConnect;
import en.xxx.project.beans.LoginBean;
public class LoginDao {
  public boolean vaildate(LoginBean bean)
  {
    boolean result = false;
    Connection connection=DBConnect.getConn();
    String sql="select * from user where username=? and password=?";
    try {
      PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, bean.getUserName());
      ps.setString(2, bean.getPassword());
      ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
      result=rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    return result;
  }
}
```

Servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import project.dao.LoginDao;
import project.beans.LoginBean;
import project.conn.*;
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
      String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
      LoginBean bean=new LoginBean();
      LoginDao dao=new LoginDao();
      bean.setUserName(uname);
      bean.setPassword(pass);
      if(dao.vaildate(bean))
      {
        //Here i should write the query
        response.sendRedirect("index.html");
      }
      else
      {
        response.sendRedirect("Login.html");
      }
  }
}
```

Conn package:

```
package project.conn;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class DBConnect {
  public static Connection getConn() {
    Connection con = null;
    String loadDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx";
    String dbUSERNAME = "root";
    String dbPASSWORD = "xxx";
    try {
      Class.forName(loadDriver);
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUSERNAME, dbPASSWORD);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rewrite to get very specific? The title too needs a rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Hi, is it clear now?

Comment: You should not query the database directly in the servlet. The query should be encapsulated in the DAO. I.e. in a method like getUserId(LoginBean loginBean)

Comment: @DrHopfen and can you please write some code bcs i am having some difficulties, thank you

Comment: SO is not meant to do your homework. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions To write a working answer we would also need to know the structure of your database. The idea should be to implement the method in the Dao and then call i.e. dao.getUserId() in the servlet.

Comment: @DrHopfen The structure of the database is :table is called user. The columns are: id_user,name,surname,email,username,password

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the Dao class the following way.

```
package en.xx.project.dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import en.xxx.project.conn.DBConnect;
import en.xxx.project.beans.LoginBean;
public class LoginDao {
  public boolean vaildate(LoginBean bean)
  {
    boolean result = false;
    Connection connection=DBConnect.getConn();
    String sql="select * from user where username=? and password=?";
    try {
      PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, bean.getUserName());
      ps.setString(2, bean.getPassword());
      ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
      result=rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }    
    return result;
  }

  public String getUserId(LoginBean bean){
    String result = "";
    Connection connection = DBConnect.getConn();
    String sql = "select id_user from user where username=?"
    try {
      PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, bean.getUserName());
      ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
      result=rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Then just call `dao.getUserId(bean)` in your servlet. Note that the code is not tested and should be refactored. For example the connection should be reused by the dao. Also error handling or validation that a valid userId is returned is completely missing.